# How to find out where a VisualForce Page has been referenced in order to delete it?

Tags: visualforce

I wish to delete a VisualForce page. While trying to delete it, I am getting the following error:

**Error Message:**
[image: sc1]

I navigated to the VF page in setup and clicked the "`Where is this Used?`" button and found that only the controller was listed. How do I find out if a custom link or button is using the page?

**Screenshot of developer console:**
[image: sc2]

**VF page Code:**

```html
<apex:page standardController="Lineitems__c"  extensions="LaunchLineitemCreateExt" tabStyle="Opportunity" > 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Code**

```java
public with sharing class LaunchLineitemCreateExt {
     public LaunchLineitemCreateExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
     }
}
```

Comment: Got an IDE? Pull down metadata and use find in files is an option...

Comment: @Girbot I use the Salesforce Developer Console. I don't have any other IDE.

Comment: I have installed the `salesforce advanced code searcher` chrome extension. It too lists only the controller. Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing an IDE is the best options here.

The SFDX + VS Code IDE is available and can be setup in couple of minutes (mostly) if your IT team allows it, you can pull all the metadata and do a global search. This will ensure you are not missing dynamic references, labels, JS, buttons where this page is used.

Also keep a lookout if the dynamic references are being fetched from custom setting or metadata record.